# CSS Div Scroll Height

Tags: javascript, css, scrolltop

I am trying to recreate the effect seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/aATHd/2/

But I am trying to animate the height. For some reason, it works fine when I scroll down, but upon scrolling up, the height doesn't change back to normal. Any ideas?

Here is what I have now: http://justinledelson.com/new/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250){
     $('#header').animate({"height":"100px"}, 1500);
  } 
  else{
    $('#header').animate({"height":"470px"}, 1);
  }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Scrolling up doesn't work in te js fiddle either.

Comment: This isn't a solution, but one thing that could benefit you would be to add a class after each action. Something like ```expanded``` and ```collapsed``` for each situation, and check if that class is present before doing the animation. That way the animations won't trigger until it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Although I said that this wasn't a solution for your problem, it seems that it's actually a solution.

Add a class after each action. Something like `expanded` and `collapsed` for each situation, and check if that class is present before doing the animation. That way the animations won't trigger until it's necessary.

This avoids triggering the animation multiple times queuing the animation. That's why if you scrolled down a lot of times and scrolled back to top, the "expanding" animation triggered long after you scrolled up (it had to wait that each "collapsing" animation ended)

My test was:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    var $header = $('#header');
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50){  // x should be from where you want this to happen from top//
     if (!$header.hasClass('collapsed')) {
       $header.animate({"height":"100px"}, 1500, function() {
         $header.toggleClass('expanded collapsed');
       });
     }
    } 
    else{
      if (!$header.hasClass('expanded')) {
        $header.animate({"height":"470px"}, 1, function() {
         $header.toggleClass('expanded collapsed');
       });
      }
    }

});
```

header should start with `expanded` class